# Gridview is loading multiple times

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have a gridview which is working fine (i.e. it is loading 4 rows) with bound controls. this grid view has 4 rows:

```
Ex: <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Classification" DataField="ClassType" />
```

but when I changed the gridview with itemtemplate then my **gridview is loading 4 times**

Structure:-

```
Gridview
- template field
-- Item template

<%# Eval("ClassType")%>
```

on code behind I am loading this via: (on page_load)

```
 gvResultSet.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 gvResultSet.DataBind();
```

**Code**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvResultSet" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">



<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
             <table class="tb">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Classification
        </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="record">
        <td>
          <%# Eval("ClassType")%>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you checked contents of `ds.Tables[0]` ?

Comment: Yes, it has 4 rows and working fine with bound controls

Comment: If it has 4 rows, then obviously 4 lines will be displayed for grid, implies , grid is loaded once only. Clarify the confusion here ( if any).

Comment: when working with item template, it is loading 4 gridviews. It should actually load 4 rows in a gridview

Comment: Can you show your actual markup rather than this pseudo code?

Comment: You might be interpreting 4 rows to 4 gridview, i think, you can try the answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set gridview's property `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`. This will solve your issue.

**Update**

My Recommendation is to use `Repeater` Control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="tb">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Status
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Start Time
                        </th>
                        <th class="date">
                            End Time
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            MAX Date found
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Classification
                        </th>
                        <th class="last">
                            Read Description
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="record">
                <td>
                    <div class="toggle enabled">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="overflow">
                    <%# Eval("Name")%>
                </td>
                <td class="overflow">
                    12/23/2014 6:20:47
                </td>
                <td>
                    12/23/2014 6:27:21
                </td>
                <td class="date">
                    12/23/2014
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("ClassType")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody> </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I already did, but that's not the issue. Gridview has accurate number of columns. My issue is that when using item template my page has 4 gridview, I am expecting 1 gridview with 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler this way

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="tb">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Classification">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("ClassType")%></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle CssClass="record" />
</asp:GridView>
```

If you want header inside th, do this after `DataBind`

```
gvResultSet.DataBind();
gvResultSet.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```